Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components
I have an "admin" page on my NextJs application using vercel postgress and what I am trying to do is, after filling in the inputs and clicking on "Create user" button, new user should get created. But after clicking on the button I get an error:

Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.

However, if I refresh the page, new user is created, so I guess it is some sort of client/server side components that is causing this problem. Here is all the code:
Admin/page.tsx:
import { User, getUsers } from '@/api';
import DeleteUser from '@/components/DeleteUser.tsx';
import AddUser from '@/components/AddUser.tsx';

export default async function UsersPage() {
  const users = await getUsers();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full mb-[800px]">
        <AddUser />
      {users.map((user: User) => (
        <div className="flex justify-between border-b w-[400px]" key={user.id}>
          <div className="flex gap-4">
            <h1>{user.name}</h1>
            <p>{user.email}</p>
            <p>{user.age}</p>
          </div>
          <DeleteUser id={user.id} />
        </div>
      ))}

    </div>
  );
}

api/create-user/route.ts:
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(request: Request) {

  const { name, email, age } = await request.json();

  try {
    if (!name || !email || !age) throw new Error('Please fill in all the graphs');

    await sql`INSERT INTO users (name, email, age) VALUES (${name}, ${email}, ${age});`;
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error }, { status: 500 });
  }

  const users = await sql`SELECT * FROM users;`;

  return NextResponse.json({ users }, { status: 200 });
}

actions.ts:
'use server'
import { createUser, deleteUser } from '@/api';
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
export async function createUserAction(formData: FormData) {
  const { name, email, age } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  revalidatePath('/admin')
  return createUser(name as string, email as string, age as string);
}

export async function deleteUserAction(id: number) {
  revalidatePath('/admin')
  await deleteUser(id);
}

components/AddUser.tsx:
'use client'

import { createUserAction } from '@/app/actions.ts';
import React from 'react';

export default function AddUser() {

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

    function handleOpen() {
        setOpen(true)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleOpen} className='bg-slate-400 p-3 rounded-xl mb-10 mt-[200px]'>Add new user</button>
            {open && <form action={createUserAction} className="translate-x-[-50%] left-[50%] rounded-xl h-[400px] flex flex-col gap-4 w-[500px] text-black absolute bg-slate-700 p-10 py-20">
                        <input type="text" name="name" className='h-[40px] rounded-lg'/>
                        <input type="text" name="email" className='h-[40px] rounded-lg'/>
                        <input type="text" name="age" className='h-[40px] rounded-lg'/>
                        <button type="submit" className="bg-red-500 text-white h-[40px] rounded-lg mt-auto">
                            Create User
                        </button>
                    </form>}
        </div>
    )
}

api.ts:
 export const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
 export async function createUser(name: string, email: string, age: string) {
    return await fetch(BASE_URL + '/api/create-user', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, age }),
    });
  }

I tried moving my AddUser.tsx client component to Admin/page.tsx and removed state and just made a plain form to fill, in order to get rid of "use client" in AddUser.tsx, but still got the same error. Thanks in advance.

Turns out, the error was caused because I had written "return" instead of "await" in actions.ts:
  await createUser(name as string, email as string, age as string);

instead of
  return createUser(name as string, email as string, age as string);

Dumb mistake.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
